# I want to drag an image between two PictureBox controls while moving the Image with the mouse cursor (chess game vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, picturebox, chess

I know how to do the first part of my question but it doesn't look good in the game when the piece image just disappear off the original board square and then appear on the target square, so I want the piece to remain visible while moving with the mouse movement between the 64's PictureBox controls that I've made as the board squares. Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Drawing.Image
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class frmMain
    Dim MovingFinished As Boolean
    Dim BlackPiece(5) As Image
    Dim WhitePiece(5) As Image
    Dim BaseCorX As Integer
    Dim BaseCorY As Integer
    Dim TargetCorX As Integer
    Dim TargetCorY As Integer
    Dim BoardSquare As Integer = 65
    Dim PieceImg As Image
    Dim PicBox As PictureBox

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        BlackPiece(0) = My.Resources.BP
        BlackPiece(1) = My.Resources.BR
        BlackPiece(2) = My.Resources.BN
        BlackPiece(3) = My.Resources.BB
        BlackPiece(4) = My.Resources.BQ
        BlackPiece(5) = My.Resources.BK

        WhitePiece(0) = My.Resources.WP
        WhitePiece(1) = My.Resources.WR
        WhitePiece(2) = My.Resources.WN
        WhitePiece(3) = My.Resources.WB
        WhitePiece(4) = My.Resources.WQ
        WhitePiece(5) = My.Resources.WK

        a1.Image = WhitePiece(1)
        b1.Image = WhitePiece(2)
        c1.Image = WhitePiece(3)
        d1.Image = WhitePiece(4)
        e1.Image = WhitePiece(5)
        f1.Image = WhitePiece(3)
        g1.Image = WhitePiece(2)
        h1.Image = WhitePiece(1)
        a2.Image = WhitePiece(0)
        b2.Image = WhitePiece(0)
        c2.Image = WhitePiece(0)
        d2.Image = WhitePiece(0)
        e2.Image = WhitePiece(0)
        f2.Image = WhitePiece(0)
        g2.Image = WhitePiece(0)
        h2.Image = WhitePiece(0)

        a8.Image = BlackPiece(1)
        b8.Image = BlackPiece(2)
        c8.Image = BlackPiece(3)
        d8.Image = BlackPiece(4)
        e8.Image = BlackPiece(5)
        f8.Image = BlackPiece(3)
        g8.Image = BlackPiece(2)
        h8.Image = BlackPiece(1)
        a7.Image = BlackPiece(0)
        b7.Image = BlackPiece(0)
        c7.Image = BlackPiece(0)
        d7.Image = BlackPiece(0)
        e7.Image = BlackPiece(0)
        f7.Image = BlackPiece(0)
        g7.Image = BlackPiece(0)
        h7.Image = BlackPiece(0)

        For Each a As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf a Is PictureBox Then
                AddHandler a.MouseDown, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseDown
                AddHandler a.MouseMove, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseMove
                AddHandler a.DragEnter, AddressOf PictureBox_DragEnter
                AddHandler a.DragDrop, AddressOf PictureBox_DragDrop
                a.AllowDrop = True
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Dim a As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        PieceImg = a.Image
        PicBox = a
        BaseCorX = a.Location.X
        BaseCorY = a.Location.Y
        txt1.Text = BaseCorX
        txt2.Text = BaseCorY
        If Not a.Image Is Nothing Then
            MovingFinished = True
            TextBox1.Text = MovingFinished
            If a.Image Is BlackPiece(0) Then
            End If
        Else
            MovingFinished = False
            TextBox1.Text = MovingFinished
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        If MovingFinished = True Then
            'PicBox.Location = New Point(PicBox.Left - (TargetCorX - e.X), PicBox.Top - (TargetCorY - e.Y))
            PicBox.DoDragDrop(PieceImg, DragDropEffects.Move)
            TextBox2.Text = "tae0"
        End If
        MovingFinished = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
        If Not e.KeyState = 8 Then
            Dim a As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
            TargetCorX = a.Location.X
            TargetCorY = a.Location.Y
            txt1.Text = TargetCorX
            txt2.Text = TargetCorY

            If Not a Is PicBox Then
                If PieceImg Is BlackPiece(0) Then
                    TextBox2.Text = "pawnBlackPiece"
                    If BaseCorY - TargetCorY = -BoardSquare And BaseCorX = TargetCorX Then
                        If a.Image Is Nothing Then
                            a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                            PicBox.Image = Nothing
                        Else
                            TextBox2.Text = "There is a piece there"
                        End If
                    ElseIf BaseCorY - TargetCorY = -65 And BaseCorX - TargetCorX = -65 Or BaseCorY - TargetCorY = -65 And TargetCorX - BaseCorX = -65 Then
                        a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                        PicBox.Image = Nothing

                        TextBox2.Text = "good"
                    End If

                ElseIf PieceImg Is BlackPiece(1) Then
                    a.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                    PicBox.Image = Nothing
                ElseIf PieceImg Is BlackPiece(2) Then
                ElseIf PieceImg Is BlackPiece(3) Then
                ElseIf PieceImg Is BlackPiece(4) Then
                ElseIf PieceImg Is BlackPiece(5) Then
                End If

            Else
                TextBox2.Text = "DO nothing"
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: actual drag drop is probably not the easiest way to go.  when they move a piece make the picturebox move across the screen so the image appears to move.  When they drop it (mouseup), move the image from pbFrom to pbTo and reset the moving pb to it original location.

Comment: yeah I thought about that and although it seems to be a working solution but the only problem is the background transparency of the picture boxes while dragging, I mean it will never look good when you drag a piece of chess to move it and you see that the square under it is moving with it's back color over the board! lol

Comment: that depends on how the rest is written.

Comment: well I thought it's all explained in the post above, anyway again.. it's a chess board of 64 picture boxes showing png's of the pieces from resources and I tried graphics, I move the pieces by drag-and-drop the image from a box to another. I tried drawings before but didn't like the concept as I must keep track and record for every movement (pieces/board squares) for the sake of game record and tactics, because as you know that on-the-fly graphics is not actually an object to hoc or call by name. do you have a better approach?

Comment: I would use only ONE picturebox, but with a ChessBoard Class that virtually tracks everything (moves, items location...) and controls what are going to be drawn on the picturebox (And I'll use GDI+ codes like those explained on Bob Powell's blog) But that means rewriting the entire code... Otherwise, what about "layered windows" and unmanaged code. You can also replace your cursor by the piece by using a custom cursor instead of a picturebox. An I thought the DragDrop had a custom bitmap to display (never tried that last idea though)

Comment: well if the code is not object oriented and you dont like the idea of graphics, the options are pretty limited. if a board obj provided the square color, you could subclass the PB, overriding `OnPaintBackground` so that when the pb moves, whatever is beneath - empty squares or other pieces - shows thru in the non image area. not trivial, but doable.  You could also use a special just pb for the moving part to prevent overkill.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the `OnPaintBackgorund` method?